# What is the fastest (possibly unsafe) way to read a byte[]?

Tags: c#, multithreading, buffer

I'm working on a server project in C#, and after a TCP message is received, it is parsed, and stored in a byte[] of exact size. (Not a buffer of fixed length, but a byte[] of an absolute length in which all data is stored.)

Now for reading this byte[] I'll be creating some wrapper functions (also for compatibility), these are the signatures of all functions I need:

```
public byte ReadByte();
public sbyte ReadSByte();
public short ReadShort();
public ushort ReadUShort();
public int ReadInt();
public uint ReadUInt();
public float ReadFloat();
public double ReadDouble();
public string ReadChars(int length);
public string ReadString();
```

The string is a \0 terminated string, and is probably encoded in ASCII or UTF-8, but I cannot tell that for sure, since I'm not writing the client.

The data exists of:

```
byte[] _data;
int _offset;
```

Now I can write all those functions manually, like this:

```
public byte ReadByte()
{
    return _data[_offset++];
}

public sbyte ReadSByte()
{
    byte r = _data[_offset++];
    if (r >= 128) return (sbyte)(r - 256);
    else return (sbyte)r;
}

public short ReadShort()
{
    byte b1 = _data[_offset++];
    byte b2 = _data[_offset++];
    if (b1 >= 128) return (short)(b1 * 256 + b2 - 65536);
    else return (short)(b1 * 256 + b2);
}

public short ReadUShort()
{
    byte b1 = _data[_offset++];
    return (short)(b1 * 256 + _data[_offset++]);
}
```

But I wonder if there's a faster way, not excluding the use of unsafe code, since this seems to cost too much time for simple processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to map the contents of the array to a struct (providing your structure is indeed static):

http://geekswithblogs.net/taylorrich/archive/2006/08/21/88665.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
struct Message
{
    public int id;
    [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=50)] 
    public string text;
}

void OnPacket(byte[] packet)
{
    GCHandle pinnedPacket = GCHandle.Alloc(packet, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    Message msg = (Message)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
        pinnedPacket.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
        typeof(Message));        
    pinnedPacket.Free();
}
```

Comment: An interesting approach - I wonder if it's faster. May have to benchmark these... Thanks =)

Comment: This isn't actually what I was looking for, and it's not static.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class, in the System namespace. It contains methods for turning parts of byte[]s into other primitive types. I've used it in similar situations and have found it suitably quick.

As for decoding strings from byte[]s, use the classes that derive from the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class, in the System.Text namespace, specifically the [GetString(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) method (and its overloads).

Comment: I'm aware of the BitConverter class, I'll give it another try, but I think something went wrong last time I tried it.

Comment: If you want to post another question regarding specifically your trouble with BitConverter, post a link to the question here and I'll take a look.

Comment: I found the problem again, if byte[] _data = { 2, 1, 0, 9 };, then BitConverter.ToInt32(_data, 0) results in: {9, 0, 1, 2} -> INT32

Comment: Also for the Encoding.(encoding type).GetString(), how do I set it to read it as a \0 terminated string? Because they read a length-prefixed string by default.

Comment: So to change it I just need to reverse the data, but how about reading string then?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx).

A BinaryReader is a stream decorator so you would have to wrap the `byte[]` in a MemoryStream or attach the Reader directly to the network stream.

And then you have

```
int ReadInt32()
char[] ReadChars(int count)
```

etc.

---

#### Edit: Apparently you want 'faster execution'.

That means you are looking for an optimization in the conversion(s) from `byte[]`, after those bytes have been received over (network) I/O.

In other words, you are trying to optimize the part that only takes up (an estimated) 0.1% of the time. Totally futile.

Comment: I know, but that's definitely not faster, because you need to wrap the data in a memory stream, then in a binary reader, and the binary reader wraps it into a memory stream before it actually parses it.

Comment: @Aidia, your question is unclear about what you actually want. In the last sentence you talk about the amount of work, that's another faster. A more sensible one. I will edit.